# Magento 2 : Add custom Gift message programmatically during checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, giftmessage

I want to SET gift message programmatically in current order(one message for whole order) during Checkout.
Currently, I trying using sales_order_save_after  event to edit order but didn't get succeed.

any another approach to do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got the easiest way.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $session,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepository,
    \Magento\GiftMessage\Model\MessageFactory $messageFactory
) {
    $this->session = $session;
    $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    $this->messageFactory = $messageFactory;
}
public function test(){
  $quoteId = $this->session->getQuote()->getId();
  $giftMessage = $this->messageFactory->create();
  $giftMessage->setMessage('your text');
  $giftObj = $giftMessage->save();
  $quote->setGiftMessageId($giftObj->getId());
  $quote->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get Gift message for order item using this code.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\GiftMessage\Api\OrderItemRepositoryInterface $orderItemGiftRepo
) {
    $this->orderItemGiftRepo = $orderItemGiftRepo;
}

public function getGiftMessage($orderId, $orderItemId)
{ 
    $giftMessage = $this->orderItemGiftRepo->get($orderId, $orderItemId);
    $giftMessage->getMessage(); // This will give you message
}

public function setGiftMessage($orderId)
{
 $giftMessage = $this->orderItemGiftRepo->get($orderId);
 $giftMessage->setMessage('custommessage'); 
}
```

Hope this will help you !!

Comment: how do I set gift message for the whole order?

Comment: you don't need to pass order item id then, skip that field.

Comment: how can I set my message    $giftMessage = $this->orderGiftRepo->get($order);
        $giftMessage->setMessage('custommessage');

Comment: code updated, please check

Comment: this is not working as I try to do this  just after order place and got below error No item with the provided ID was found in the Order. Verify the ID and try again

Comment: you have to pass id of order properly, just only print orderid, if you are getting then it works only, if not please try to get orderid by another way

Answer (score 0):

if you want to  add information after placing order then you may use "checkout_onepage_controller_success_action" this event to add your custom data